# How to mount bind in fstab?

Tags: mount, fstab, bind

Here is my fstab entry :

```
"/mnt/c/Users/clego/OneDrive - ESEO/Cours/I2/" /home/clego/I2 none defaults,bind 0 0
```

But when I type `sudo mount -a`

I got

```
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 1 -- ignored
```

Comment: Related: [Mounting my PC Box network drive onto wsl2 with drvfs works manually but not in /etc/fstab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1392262/mounting-my-pc-box-network-drive-onto-wsl2-with-drvfs-works-manually-but-not-in)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are not allowed to use " (or '). You need to use [codepoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters).

Use `\040` for a space. It is the octal codepoint for a space. So like this:

```
/mnt/c/Users/clego/OneDrive\040-\040ESEO/Cours/I2/ /home/clego/I2 none defaults,bind 0
```

The `-` should not be special but that would be `\056`.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `defaults,` is a bit of a cargo cult. The special `defaults` mount option is just a placeholder for when you don't want to set any options at all (keeping everything at the default settings) but need to fill the fourth column of fstab so that the fifth column parses correctly. `defaults,something` is thus exactly equivalent to just `something`. [The source code](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/3443cea28263e0ec554ca0e7317e40c9166c48fd/libmount/src/optmap.c#L147) of `mount` in util-linux confirms that `defaults` maps to "nothing at all".

Comment: @TooTea I suppose it can be useful if you use a script to add/remove options. Explicit `defaults` means the script doesn't have to handle the limiting case speciallyh.